# Creating rounded images with auk in xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the third party library auk to display my scrolling images. Is there a way to have the images in the scroll view have rounded edges?

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auk doesn't give you a method you are looking for. If it needed, you should add a method to the library or use a hacky way like the following,

```
// this code should be placed after scrollView.auk.show() method call
scrollView.subviews
    .forEach { sv in
        sv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        sv.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 // change a value you want
    }
```

FYI, the library set .scaleAspectToFit as default to contentMode of UIImageView. So, in some case, my hacky suggestion may be not useful if an image doesn't cover corners of UIImageView.

I recommend you taking first way which I suggest you. Add a feature you need to the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the property of CALayer [cornerRadius](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius) to display images with corner radius. (Change value of that property on a page view).

Unfortunately, the [AUK library](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk) does not contain methods to customise display of images.

I think you have a couple of solutions:

1. Include the sources of the library into your project and add customisation callback in [createPage](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk/blob/742c315fb7b18e73c5d9483c4863dc127c676bdc/Auk/Auk.swift#L406) method.
2. Subclass AUK class and override [createPage](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk/blob/742c315fb7b18e73c5d9483c4863dc127c676bdc/Auk/Auk.swift#L406) method. Also you will have to  create new [UIScroll extension](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk/blob/master/Auk/UIScrollView%2BAuk.swift) with your class as property.